# Install php7.4 on ubuntu 22.10 Kinetic Kudu

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am trying to install php7.4 on ubuntu 22.10 Kinetic Kudu.

by using this:

```
sudo apt install php7.4-fpm
```

I am getting following error:

```
E: Package 'php7.4-fpm' has no installation candidate
```

So I tried following method:

```
sudo apt update && apt upgrade -y
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt update
```

But Getting following error while running `sudo apt update`

```
The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
```

How can i install php7.4 on ubuntu 22.10 Kinetic Kudu??

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I suspect there is an issue with the ppa not being set up for 22.10. I don't think there's much that can be done until the maintainer updates the ppa.

Comment: @Al_ Yes, I feel the same